# MomentJS Returning Date with Timestamp

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have an issue where the date fields being submitted are returning date with timestamp, rather than just the date with the timestamp set to `00:00:00`. This code works for other instances where I am trying to achieve this process, but for some reason it is not working and I'm curious if the conversion has to happen within my form in my view or should happen on the back-end within my routes.

**Route:**

```
.post(function(req, res){


        models.Creator.findAll({
            order: 'createDate DESC',
            where: {
                dataDateStart: {
                    $gte: moment(req.body.startDate).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
                },
                dataDateEnd: {
                    $lte: moment(req.body.endDate).utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
                }
            },
            include: [{
                model: models.User,
                where: { 
                    organizationId: req.user.organizationId,
                },
                attributes: ['organizationId', 'userId']
            }],
            limit: 10
        }).then(function() { 
            res.redirect('/app');
        }).catch(function(error){
            res.send(error);
        })
    });
```

**Outputted where clause:**

```
WHERE `creator`.`data_date_start` >= '2016-06-07 04:00:00' AND `creator`.`data_date_end` <= '2016-06-11 04:00:00' ORDER BY createDate DESC LIMIT 10;
```

As you can see the issue is that `04:00:00` appears instead of `00:00:00`

**View:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="creator-search-form col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <h1 id="search-header">Filter Feed</h1>
        <form action="/app" method="post" class="creator-filter-fields">
            <p>Date Range:</p>
            <input type="date" name="startDate">
            <input type="date" name="endDate">
            <button type="submit" id="creator-filter-submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that what is going on in your situation is that somewhere downstream from Moment, your date without a time is being interpreted as local time, and then converted to UTC. I would guess that your server is set to UTC-4 (US Eastern Daylight?), and that is why you are seeing what you do.

When you change from using `.format('YYYY-MM-DD')` to just `.format()`, your resultant string includes all time parts and an offset, and look like this:

```
moment.utc('2016-01-01').format()
"2016-01-01T00:00:00Z"
```

Because the above date is completely unambiguous, your whatever is changing the time in your stack doesn't make any odd decisions about how to interpret it, and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the queried value from date elements are strings in the format YYYY-MM-DD, then you can get the result by

```
moment.utc(value).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

where the value is the date string.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the comment, but your solution provides the exact same output as what I am already getting. Still not producing the date string

Comment: That should not be the case. You can try it out on the console window of the browser (given that moment.js library exists). moment.utc('2015-01-01 00:00:00').format("YYYY-MM-DD") ==>>> "2015-01-01". The problem might be somewhere else. Please console.log req.body.startDate and req.body.endDate.

Comment: You are right, I added `console.log('Unformatted: ' + req.body.startDate);
  console.log('Formatted: ' + moment.utc(req.body.startDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));` and receive `Unformatted: 2016-06-13
Formatted: 2016-06-13`. This seems to indicate that it might be Sequelize, my ORM that is appending the `04:00:00`. Would you agree?

Comment: I also think that the 04:00:00 has to do with local time. If I run This is the `new Date(date);` the output is in the format of `Thu Jun 09 2016 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)` For some reason I think setting the format to just the date is still taking the local time into consideration and offsetting the hours by setting it to 4am.

Comment: I fixed the issue by removing `"YYYY-MM-DD"` from `.format`. For a reason I will explain in my answer this modification reverts to local time